# Не получается реализовать белый список для доступа к телеграм боту (python, sqlite3, telebot)

Tags: python, sqlite3, telebot

Имеется бд на sqlite3 со списком пользователей, которые могут посылать команды боту. не получается реализовать, что бы это работало. На сообщение от любого пользователя пишет "Доступ ограничен", даже если пользователь имеется в бд.

```
import telebot
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

con = sqlite3.connect('white_list.db')

cursor = con.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM white_list WHERE users"
cursor.execute(sql)
user_name = cursor.fetchall()

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id not in user_name)
def access_msg(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Доступ ограничен')
```

Работает, только если принудительно указать на номер элемента.

```
user_name = user_name[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить строку

```
user_name = cursor.fetchall()
```

на

```
user_name = {item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()}
```

Хотя не очень понятно, почему вы называете эту переменную user_name, если подразумевается, что это должен быть список айдишников.

Comment: спасибо, помогло. над названием переменной не очень заморачивался.